# how to re route and dial failed outbound calls through different PRI in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I need a solution to this problem. When I dial through one PRI line x having group g0.
`dial(DAHDI/g0/9xxxxxxxxx,35,rt)`
and if that particular PRI is down(suppose signal is not down but not able to dial)for some reason, then how to re route and dial this number through another PRI. So that the dial does not fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can put pri into groups  using dahdi.conf, just set both pri to same group number

You also can use DIALSTATUS variable and GotoIF in dialplan to do hunting by dialplan(described in any asterisk book)